# How can I connect my Denon AVR-1913 Audio Video Receiver to Windows 8.1 XBox Music App?

Tags: windows-8.1, dlna, xbox-music

I have a Denon Audio Video Receiver hooked up to my WiFi network.

I can "see" it from my Windows Phone, and from Windows Media Player.  If I use the Denon controls, I can see my music collection on my laptop and can play files via DLNA.

Since the XBox Music App for Windows 8.1 is so kick-*ss, I'd love to be able to play files from it directly to the Denon, but the Denon does not appear in the Devices charm when accessed from XBox Music.

I do have the Denon AVR-1913 visible in the main Devices charm, it is recognized by Windows 8.1 however it is listed as "Not Windows Certified" - I believe this may be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) I was able to find the answer.

By default, Windows won't "Play To" any device that is not "Windows Certified".

Having said that, there is a pretty simply workaround that in my case worked flawlessly.  I wanted to post the answer here to make it easy to find for future visitors.

Microsoft has posted the workaround on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows8_1-pictures/use-non-certified-play-to-devices-in-windows-81/660c16a5-33e8-4a1a-9466-6fa2bfe07956).

Essentially, you need to open the Registry Editor, either by using Windows Start Menu and searching for "registry editor", or by clicking WindowsKey+R and entering `regedit`.

Go to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft` key and add a key named `PlayTo`.  Under this new key, add a 32-bit DWORD value named `ShowNonCertifiedDevices` and set the value to `0x01` (hexadecimal).  Restart your computer, and voila, the device is now visible from the XBox Music App.

I'd like to give props to [@allquixotic](https://superuser.com/users/144607/allquixotic) for helping me find the workaround document in the chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11846110#11846110).